# Calculate Total hours between two time using Masked textbox in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, maskedtextbox

I tried below code but not working proberly .calculate total hours between two time  using a masked textbox textchanged using wpf . Please help me

xaml page:

```
<msk:MaskedTextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5,5,5,5" Height="30" Text="{Binding Path=FromTime}" Name="txt_starttime" Mask="00:00" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextChanged="txt_totalhours_TextChanged" />

<msk:MaskedTextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Margin="5,5,5,5" Height="30" Text="{Binding Path=ToTime}" Name="txt_endtime" Mask="00:00" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextChanged="txt_totalhours_TextChanged"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{Binding Path=TotalHours}" Name="txt_totalhours" TextChanged="txt_totalhours_TextChanged"/>
```

code behind :

```
private void txt_totalhours_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null == txt_totalhours || null == txt_starttime || null == txt_endtime)
            return;
        //if (lb_weekDays.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        //{
        string StartTimeText = txt_starttime.Text;
        string EndTimeText = txt_endtime.Text;
        string[] Startparts = StartTimeText.Split(':');
        string[] Endparts = EndTimeText.Split(':');
        var resultStartHour = Int32.MinValue;
        var isIntstarttimeHour = Int32.TryParse(Startparts[0], out resultStartHour);

        var resultEndHour = Int32.MinValue;
        var isIntendtimeHour = Int32.TryParse(Endparts[0], out resultEndHour);

        var resultHour = isIntstarttimeHour ? ((isIntendtimeHour ? (resultEndHour - resultStartHour) : resultStartHour)) : (isIntendtimeHour ? resultEndHour : 0);
        int resHour = resultHour;

        var resultStartMin = Int32.MinValue;
        var isIntstarttimeMin = Int32.TryParse(Startparts[1], out resultStartMin);

        var resultEndMin = Int32.MinValue;
        var isIntendtimeMin = Int32.TryParse(Endparts[1], out resultEndMin);

        var resultMin = isIntstarttimeMin ? ((isIntendtimeMin ? (resultEndMin - resultStartMin) : resultStartMin)) : (isIntendtimeMin ? resultEndMin : 0);
        int resMin = resultMin;
        int lbCount = lb_weekDays.SelectedItems.Count;

        int ab = 0, abc = 0;
        ab = resHour * lbCount;
        abc = resMin * lbCount;
        if (abc > 59)
        {
            int quotient = 0;
            quotient = abc / 60;
            ab = ab + quotient;

            int remainder = 0;
            remainder = abc % 60;
            abc = remainder;
        }
        txt_totalhours.Text = ab + ":" + abc;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("Please Select WeekDays Before Enter Time");
        //}

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a TimeSpan to do the heavy lifting for you. Create two DateTime variables with your start and end times and use the resulting TimeSpan from subtracting the earlier time from later time to get the total hours between the two.

```
var dt1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2);
var dt2 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1.55);
var total = (dt2 - dt1).TotalHours;
```

Comment: If this answer helped you JohnPaul please accept it